# Issues with Angular4 routing with Child routes stacking on each other

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing, angular-router

I'll just get to it:

//App Routing Module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'index',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'index',
                component: IndexComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                component: AboutComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'contact',
                component: ContactComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'register',
                component: RegisterComponent,
            },
            {
                path: "**",
                component: NotfoundComponent
            }               
        ]
    },

];
```

Building my routes upon this configuration, when I navigate to routes using for example ...

```
<a [routerLink]="['./login']"> Login </a>
```

Each route I navigate to stack on top of each other, what's causing this?

//App Component html

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <router-outlet> </router-outlet>

</div>
```

// Home component html (shortened version)
    ### This place is the navigation and i made it stationery, so every other 
    route can load underneath it
    
        
             Login 
             Register 
             Contact

```
//I load children route in here

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>



### This is the footer, Also made stationery, so it appears in every other
### route that loads above

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <footer> </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try with `[routerLink]="['/login']"` i.e. without the dot?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation to see how the router links work? It discusses what it means for a route to start with a `./`. The intended behavior is to "stack" on the current route. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I tried removing the  dot, same thing. I even tried removing the dot and forward slash. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it . There was nothing wrong with my configuration. I just didn't import reactive form module, and form builder

Whew!!!